# Find the max value in a column of app engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, max

I have a table in google app engine datastore as `ItemData`with columns as below.

> item_no, letter, f_no, s_no, t_no

I need to get the max value in `item_no` column.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you want that using GQL or using Datastore query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT item_no FROM " + ItemData.class.getName()
                    + " ORDER BY item_no DESC RANGE 0,1");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple solution:

1. Make sure that the property is indexed.
2. Run a query on that property. Set a sort order DESCENDING and set a limit on the number of results returned to 1.

When you run this query, you will get one entity with the maximum value.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible to get the max value directly from the datastore with a GQL query in python or java. To do that you can compare your old max value with a potential new one and save the result in a table or use **Google Cloud SQL** and use the SQL statement `SELECT MAX(article) AS article FROM shop;`